# get an MYSQL error on DATE compare

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to compare my DATE column and i getting the following error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'events.sched_expired < '2015-11-25' THEN '0' ' at line 4
```

this is my qhery:

```
UPDATE events SET events.scheduled = ( CASE sched_exp_type WHEN 'counter' and events.sched_counter <= '0' THEN '0' WHEN 'date' events.sched_expired < '2015-11-25' THEN '0' ELSE (events.scheduled) END )
```

and this is my php code:

```
 $c_date = date("Y-m-d");
echo $c_date."<br/>";
$update_sched_column = "UPDATE events SET  events.scheduled = (
CASE sched_exp_type
WHEN 'counter' and events.sched_counter <= '0' THEN '0'
WHEN 'date' events.sched_expired < '$c_date' THEN '0'
ELSE (events.scheduled)
END
)";
```

Comment: WHEN 'date' events.sched_expired < '2015-11-25' .. is not valid syntax

Comment: thank you i forgot the "AND"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `case` statement does not work as you are expecting it to work and you also have syntax mistakes. Try the following:

```
 $update_sched_column ="
     UPDATE events
     SET  events.scheduled = (
     CASE WHEN sched_exp_type = 'counter' and events.sched_counter <= '0' THEN '0'
          WHEN sched_exp_type = 'date' and events.sched_expired < '$c_date' THEN '0'
          ELSE (events.scheduled)
     END)";
```

Comment: why my query does not work as i am expecting? i just added the "and" operator that was missing but all the rest is equal to your query no?